# Error Installing TFS 2008 SP1, CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'master'

Tags: tfs

just now the dba let me connect to the database using Sql Server Management Studio, this is how i noticed that the default database for the tfs setup and service users is master, is this ok?, is this why I'm having this error?,  Let me post part of the log and the properties of the Setup user to confirm that the users are configured correctly.

Here is part of the log with the error:

```
Using workflow file from location exe. 
Executing workflow 'Quiesce ATDT'... 
Stopping Windows Service 'TFSServerScheduler'... 
Stopping Windows Service 'CoverAn'... 
Stopping Windows Service 'W3SVC'... 
Starting Windows Service 'W3SVC'... 
Disabling SQL Jobs for databases     
FSActivityLogging,TFSBuild,TFSIntegration,TFSVersionControl,TFSWorkItemTracking,TFSWorkItemTrackingAttachments,TFSWarehouse 
CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'master'. 
Retrying... 
Disabling SQL Jobs for databases
TFSActivityLogging,TFSBuild,TFSIntegration,TFSVersionControl,TFSWorkItemTracking,TFSWorkItemTrackingAttachments,TFSWarehouse 
CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'master'. 
Retrying... 
Disabling SQL Jobs for databases
TFSActivityLogging,TFSBuild,TFSIntegration,TFSVersionControl,TFSWorkItemTracking,TFSWorkItemTrackingAttachments,TFSWarehouse 
CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'master'. 
Retrying... 
Disabling SQL Jobs for databases 
TFSActivityLogging,TFSBuild,TFSIntegration,TFSVersionControl,TFSWorkItemTracking,TFSWorkItemTrackingAttachments,TFSWarehouse 
CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'master'. 
Retrying... 
Disabling SQL Jobs for databases 
TFSActivityLogging,TFSBuild,TFSIntegration,TFSVersionControl,TFSWorkItemTracking,TFSWorkItemTrackingAttachments,TFSWarehouse 
CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'master'. 
Retrying... 
Disabling SQL Jobs for databases

TFSActivityLogging,TFSBuild,TFSIntegration,TFSVersionControl,TFSWorkItemTracking,TFSWorkItemTrackingAttachments,TFSWarehouse 
SQL Error #1 
SQL Message: CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'master'. 
SQL LineNumber: 13 
SQL Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider 
SQL Procedure:  

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'master'. 
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) 
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) 
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) 
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) 
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async) 
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe) 
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() 
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.TFSQuiesce.Quiescer.DisableJobs(XPathNavigator workflow) 
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.TFSQuiesce.Quiescer.ProcessSqlDatabaseElement(XPathNavigator workflow, String action, String dbName) 
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.TFSQuiesce.Quiescer.ExecuteWorkflowStep(XPathNavigator workflow, String action, String nameAttribute) 
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.TFSQuiesce.Quiescer.ExecuteWorkflowStepWithRetry(XPathNavigator workflow, String action, String nameAttribute) 
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.TFSQuiesce.Quiescer.RunWorkflow(String workflowName) 
Exception Data: 
Key: HelpLink.ProdName, Value: Microsoft SQL Server 
Key: HelpLink.ProdVer, Value: 09.00.3054 
Key: HelpLink.EvtSrc, Value: MSSQLServer 
Key: HelpLink.EvtID, Value: 262 
Key: HelpLink.BaseHelpUrl, Value: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink 
Key: HelpLink.LinkId, Value: 20476 

Executing workflow 'Unquiesce ATDT'... 
Enabling SQL Jobs. 
Unblocking service account from accessing database TFSActivityLogging 
Unblocking service account from accessing database TFSBuild 
Unblocking service account from accessing database TFSIntegration 
Unblocking service account from accessing database TFSVersionControl 
Unblocking service account from accessing database TFSWorkItemTracking 
Unblocking service account from accessing database TFSWorkItemTrackingAttachments 
Unblocking service account from accessing database TFSWarehouse 
Stopping Windows Service 'W3SVC'... 
Starting Windows Service 'W3SVC'... 
Starting Windows Service 'TFSServerScheduler'... 
Starting Windows Service 'CoverAn'... 

Workflow 'Quiesce ATDT' failed! ExitCode = 9000. 
12/03/08 16:29:03 DDSet_Status: Process returned 9000 
12/03/08 16:29:03 DDSet_Status: Found the matching error code  for return value '9000' and it is: '29207' 
12/03/08 16:29:03 DDSet_Error:  9000 
12/03/08 16:29:03 DDSet_CARetVal: 29207 
12/03/08 16:29:03 DDSet_Status: QuietExec returned 29207 
12/03/08 16:29:03 DDSet_Exit: QuietExec ended 
MSI (s) (44:18) [16:29:03:812]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0 
MSI (s) (44:18) [16:29:03:812]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0 
Action ended 16:29:03: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.
```

Here are the properties of the setup user in SQL:

**General**
Login Name: CNBYV\SRVSTFTN
Windows Authentication
Default database: master
Default Language: English

**Server Roles**
dbcreator
public
sercurityadmin

**User Mapping**
    Map        Database               User            DefaultSchema Default Role
    Checked    master                 CNBYV\SRVSTFTN  ...           public
    Checked    TfsActivityLogging     dbo             dbo           dbo_owner, public
    Checked    TfsBuild               dbo             dbo           dbo_owner, public
    Checked    TfsIntegration         dbo             dbo           dbo_owner, public
    Checked    TfsVersionControl      dbo             dbo           dbo_owner, public
    Checked    TfsWarehouse           dbo             dbo           dbo_owner, public
    Checked    TfsWorkItemTracking    dbo             dbo           dbo_owner, public
    Checked    TfsWorkItemTrackingAttachments  dbo    dbo           dbo_owner, public

Those are the settings that i found more important, if you need more information let me know.

Thanks a lot.

PS: It was just a f*ck* pain to post the table above, i don't know why people like Markdown, if someone know how to fix it so it appears like a table please edit the question.

Juan Zamudio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add the role "sysadmin" to the setup user of TFS, i had another issues (TfsWarehouse problems) but the problem about permission denied in master was solved.

Answer (score 0):

dude go to file>sourcecontrol>workspace and edit and delte the wspace which you already mapped this will sove the issue

Comment: the question is very clear "Error installing", it has nothing to do with the normal operation of TFS,

Answer (score 0):

Actually adding the sysadmin role to the TFSSETUP account is a pretty radical thing to do. In my company that is just a big no-no. The DBAs created a database for me to play within. I tried to point tfsdb (the TFS DB setup utility) to it using H_DB_NAME but it doesn't seem to work.

Does Microsoft publish any useful details on all the possible properties one can set in the msiproperty.ini? Koz, I couldn't find much useful stuff around at all.

Microsoft, if you are listenening, I'm actually thinking of ditching TFS altogether because you can't produce and/or document your setup procedures decently.